# setRegion:animated: does not make region change

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mkmapview

I'm trying to get user location and display it in mapView with following code in `iOS6`:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
if (locations.count>0) {
    for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
        [locationList addObject:location];

        if (location != nil) {
            // Zoom to the current user location.
            MKCoordinateRegion userLocation =[mapView regionThatFits: MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 150.0, 150.0)];
            [mapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"%f,%f", mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude,mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
            NSLog(@"%f,%f", mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta,mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta);
        }
    }
}
```

}

but after location updated,`[mapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES]` does not make any change to region of `mapView`, but the user location can be display as a blue dot. the `NSLog` prints like this:

```
nan,nan
0.000000,360.000000
```

Which means nothing changed. I checked most questions related map, they just call this method and get location display in the center of map.

I want to know why how can I put user location to the map center.

Answer (score 0):

You could just turn on the MKMapView tracking mode

```
[mapView setTrackingMode:MKMapViewTrackingModeFollowsUser];
```

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong Roozbeh. Please provide some context, maybe even ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```